# Constructing a function with desired asymptotes

Tags: limits, polynomials, asymptotics

I'm having some trouble getting to terms with this. I can do the problem through trial and error, but there's something fundamental I'm missing.

**The problem**

Let's say I want to construct a function that has

- vertical asymptote at $x=-3$
- slant asymptote $y = x-1$

The vertical asymptote is simple enough. We make the function a polynomial/polynomial such that the denominator as a root at $x=-3$, so $x+3$.

In order to get a linear asymptote, we want the numerator to be a degree higher than the denominator, so let's make it $(x-1)(x-\color{blue}a)$ for some $a$.

This is where my trials and tribulations begin. I'm not entirely familiar with the mechanics of getting the asymptote I want, so I try $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x+\color{blue}1)}{x+3}$ and it gives a slant asymptote of $y=x-3$.

Next, I try $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x+\color{blue}2)}{x+3}$, which gets an asymptote of $y=x-2$.

Fine, clearly it's $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x+\color{blue}3)}{x+3}$ that gives me $y=x-1$, but as you know, that doesn't work, because the $x+3$ cancels. And I guess I *technically* get $y=x-1$, but a bit more exactly than I intended. Probably because I used the $x-1$ factor in the numerator.

So I try $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{(x-\color{red}2)(x+1)}{x+3}$ and start the process over, and when I get to $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x+4)}{x+3}$, I have my two desired asymptotes.

**Question**

Why $(x-2)(x+4)$? What is their relationship to $y=x-1$?

Is there a more formulaic way to achieve this? I assume there is, because what I did was pretty algorithmic too, just not in a good way.

I guess the general question is, does there always exist $a, b \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{x-c}$ gives the slant asymptote $y = x-d$, and what is the relation between $a, b, d$ that allows this? Can they be found more easily?

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{x-c}$, the slope of the slant asymptote is $1$ and the intercept of your slant asymptote is given by $c-a-b$. Your special case corresponds to $-3-2+4=-1$.

Comment: @Lelouch - That's *exactly* the kind of quick approach I was looking for. I'm not quite getting how $c-a-b$ becomes the intercept though. If I take the limit as $x\to\infty$ for $f(x)$, and multiply through by $1/x$, I get $x-a-b$. It feels close...

Comment: The intercept is the limit of $f(x)-x$ in your case (since the slope is $1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1/(x+3)$ has flat asymptotes as $x\to\pm\infty$.  If the "slant asymptotes" are wanted for $x\to\pm\infty$, then just add $x-1$, hence $x-1+1/(x+3)$ is one possible choice.

A more generic family is $x-1+(x+3)^{-\alpha}$ for any $\alpha>0$. Or you can add any smooth, "flat" stuff like $\beta\arctan x + \gamma\tanh x$ for any $\beta$, $\gamma$.